# matplotlib : What are possible arguments for imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-structures, arguments, colormap

I am curious about changing the colormap and the interpolation method for plotting a matrix

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matrix= [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
plt.imshow(matrix,cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

In the definition of `plt.imshow` (in the file `pyplot.py`) if found this code:

```
def imshow(
        X, cmap=None, norm=None, aspect=None, interpolation=None,
        alpha=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, origin=None, extent=None,
        shape=None, filternorm=1, filterrad=4.0, imlim=None,
        resample=None, url=None, *, data=None, **kwargs):
    __ret = gca().imshow(
        X, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=aspect,
        interpolation=interpolation, alpha=alpha, vmin=vmin,
        vmax=vmax, origin=origin, extent=extent, shape=shape,
        filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
        resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
        None else {}), **kwargs)
    sci(__ret)
    return __ret
```

However it only says `cmap=None` and `interpolation=None`.

I know that I can look up the options for these arguments in the internet ( e.g. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html),
but I would like to find the option possibilities of cmap and interpolation in the python code of matplotib itself, also to get more familiar with the data structure in python.

How can I "unearth" the options for these parameters in my code?

As an IDE I am using pycharm.

Comment: Go deeper in the call stack, Luke. :D So, next see the implementation of `gca()` and so on. However, matplotlib is partially implemented in C++, so you can't follow the rabbit hole in pure Python.

Comment: sometimes you just have to "google it" :), and some modules don't even have docs in the code.

Comment: I would love to follow the rabbit hole, also to understand these things when I don't have possible explanations from the help() function or google. So when I am at `gca()` the code says 
`def gca(**kwargs):
  return gcf().gca(**kwargs)`
And when I am at `gca(self, **kwargs)` it gets very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your python session

```
help(plt.imshow)
```

in jupyter notebook

```
?plt.imshow
```

dont know about pycharm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the online documentation of matplotlib, available at [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/).

On the homepage you may navigate to **API**

[image]

Then either look at the [matplotlib.pyplot function reference](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) or the [list of matplotlib modules](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html).

You would then arrive at the documentation page you're intested in, either

- [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) or
- [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

From there you obtain a complete overview over possible arguments and accepted values. You can directly check the source code

[image]

and often find examples of the usage linked.